# Some topological question related to set containment

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Let $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2 $ be a bounded domain(open and connected subsets) such that $A=\cup_k A_k$, where  $A_k\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2,\ k\in{\mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of bounded domains such that $A_k\subseteq A_{k+1},$ for all $k.$ Let $f:A\to B^2(0,1)$(unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$) be a continuous one-one map such that $B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)\subsetneq f(A).$ Can we conclude from this that $f^{-1}\left(B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)\right)\subseteq A_k$ for all $k\geq n$ for some $n$?

What I am able to we figure out is: If in place of $B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)\subsetneq f(A)$, we assume $B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)\subseteq f(A),$ then taking $A=B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)$, $A_k=B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2- \frac 1 k\right)$ and $f=$ inclusion map, we get that this statement won't hold. So, maybe this proper containment will help in proving this but I am unable to prove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can easily modify your counterexample (for instance, adding $B^2\left(-\frac 12,\frac 1 2\right)$ to each $A_k$), achieving $B^2\left(0,\frac 1 2\right)\subsetneq f(A)$.

Comment: I was wondering if we can add any other restriction, maybe on $f$, to say such a statement holds.

Comment: @123N The counterpart of the required claim naturally holds when the contained ball $B^2$ is *closed*. Indeed, by the Open Domain Principle, each continuous injective map $f:A\to\Bbb R^n$  defined on an open subset $A\subset \Bbb R^n$  is an open topological embedding. Thus $\{f(A_k)\}$ is an open cover of the compact set $B^2$ and so it has a finite subcover (contained in the biggest element of the subcover).